# Arrows with curly parenthesis

Tags: arrows, tikz-arrows, tikz-pic

I do not know how to us tikzpicture very well. I want to draw the picture similar that is attached. My problem is how can I add curly parenthesis between the arrow. Additionally, if you can suggest me a good tutorial about tikzpicture, I will appreciate.

[image: Protocol]

Comment: Many examples here: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something likes this. Basically `node` techniques are used here, with `decoration` that adds the braces from the starting point to the end point as shown below. `raise` and `amplitude` can be changed to suit one's need. As to the tutorial, there are many good ones (pdf, beamers, website) in the internet. you could find a couple of them easily.

```
\draw[decorate,thick,decoration={brace,amplitude=5pt,raise=4pt}] (0,0)--(0,1);
```

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,decorations.pathreplacing,arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,-1) (a){};
\node at (0,1)  (b){};
\node[right] at (5,0) (c){P};
\draw[very thick,->,>=latex', shorten <= -5pt] (b)--(c);
\draw[very thick,dashed] (0,0)node[left=1cm]{V}--(5,0);
\draw[very thick,->,>=latex', shorten >= -5pt] (c)--(a);
\draw[decorate,thick,decoration={brace,amplitude=5pt,raise=4pt}] 
(0,0)--(0,1);
\draw[decorate,thick,decoration={brace,amplitude=5pt,raise=4pt}] 
(0,-1)--(0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```